# Uninstalling product with WinRM and C#

Tags: c#, remote-access, uninstallation, winrm

I'm using WSManAutomation to remotely manage servers.
I need to install and uninstall applications on remote servers that have WinRM over HTTPS enabled. The connection is not a problem

So far the code below executes msiexec.exe in the remote host as I can see it in the list of processes but it does not execute the uninstall command.

```
 public void UninstallProduct(string path, string target, string username = null, string password = null)
    {
        IWSMan wsman = new WSManClass();
        IWSManConnectionOptions options = (IWSManConnectionOptions)wsman.CreateConnectionOptions();
        if (options != null)
        {
            try
            {
                options.UserName = username;
                options.Password = password;

                int iFlags = (int)_WSManSessionFlags.WSManFlagCredUsernamePassword;
                IWSManSession session = (IWSManSession)wsman.CreateSession(string.Format("https://{0}:5986/wsman", target), iFlags, options);
                // IWSManSession session = (IWSManSession)wsman.CreateSession(string.Format("http://{0}/wsman", target), 0, options);
                if (session != null)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        string strResource = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wmi/root/cimv2/Win32_Process";
                        string strInputParameters =string.Format("<p:Create_INPUT xmlns:p=\"{0}\"><p:CommandLine>\"{1}\"</p:CommandLine></p:Create_INPUT>", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wmi/root/cimv2/Win32_Process",path);

                        var reply = session.Invoke("Create", strResource, strInputParameters);


                        Console.WriteLine(reply);
                        Console.WriteLine();

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally 
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(options);
            }
        }

    }
```

The call to the method above would be:

```
obj.UninstallProduct(@"C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe /x {E499AB77-9B27-416CB9B6F-4A171D02BB31} /passive", "hostname", @"hostname\Administrator", "password");
```

Do you know why the command does not get executed?
Should I use another way to uninstall  a product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came across a way to do this using remote PowerShell

```
string command = string.Format("(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product  | Where-Object {$_.Name -match {0}}).Uninstall()", productName);

        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(username, securePassword);
        string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(true, target, 5986, "/wsman", shellUri, credential);
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {

            runspace.Open();

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(command);

            try
            {
                Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process");
            }
            finally
            {
                runspace.Close();
            }





        }
```